# Populating a table inside a bootstrap modal from ASP.net

Tags: jquery, asp.net, sql-server, twitter-bootstrap

I'm looking to achieve the functionality in the attached pictures. I want to populate a table from a MSSQL database. Not all of the columns present in the database table are displayed in the bootstrap modal and an additional button is added for the user to select a particular site. Once a site is selected, the site id is used to pull the data and populate the input fields in the page. What would be the most efficient way of doing this? Its my first time working with ASP so i wanted to know the best practices. Would javascript be an option for programming the select button or would ASP be better?

Any help is appreciated.

[image: modal]

[image: input fields]

Comment: What you have tried so far? I can point you to good tutorials in order to achieve your goal if you want

Comment: I tried pulling the data in a grid view. It works fine but dont know how to append the 'select' button and program it so that it populates the input field with the id of the selected table row. Please point me to any resources if you can.